# Proving a Line-integration along a parametrized curve identitiy.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

(this question were asked after studying line integrals)

1- Show that if $C$ is the graph of $y=f(x)$, $a \leq x \leq b,$ and if $F$ is a function of 2 variables defined on C, then $$\int_{C} F(x,y)dx = \int_{a}^{b} F(x, f(x))dx. $$

But I do not understand the meaning of the question, does it means that if I change the graph by its parametrization I will change the integration along the graph to the integration at the end points of the interval $[a,b]$, if so why is this correct?

Also could anyone give me a hint for the proof please?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure there is not a Jacobian missing, e.g. $\sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}$ ?

Comment: @Thomas  no there is not ..... this is exactly the question I have to answer.

Comment: Looks a bit weird to me but maybe I am not understanding. The left member when F(x,y)=1 should not be the length of C ? When parametrizing the curve by $t \rightarrow [t,f(t)]$ http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/ParaArcLength.aspx we would get a Jacobian more ? Maybe I am not getting the meaning of the let side...

Comment: May be the question contains a typo (which I am not sure of it because my professor have seen the question and did not say anything about it ..... or may be he\she was not concentrating at that moment) ..... I do not know @Thomas

Comment: Maybe I got the catch. I did not notice that you have a dx in the left member, which must be maybe intended as the integral of the differential form "F dx" over C. Before I interpreted the left integral as simply the integration of a scalar function over the manyfold C.

Comment: Maybe, as an exercise, one could see what one obtains integrating Fdy instead of Fdx :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$C$ is defined by
$$C := \{ (x,y) \ | \ x\in[a,b], \ f(x) = y \}$$
so
$$\int_{C} F(x,y)dx  = \int_{\substack{x\in [a,b] \\ y = f(x)}} F(x,y)dx = \int_{x\in[a,b]} F(x,f(x))dx =\int_a^b F(x,f(x))dx$$
This just represents any function along $C$. For example the length of the curve would be
$$\int_C \sqrt{dx^2 + dy^2} = \int_C\sqrt{1 + (\frac{dy}{dx})^2}dx = \int_a^b \sqrt{1 + (f'(x))^2}dx$$
Here $F(x,y) = \sqrt{1 + (\frac{dy}{dx})^2}$

Comment: what about the proof?

Comment: I made an edit which should be enough justification. It could almost be used as a definition in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you so much for you great effort.

Comment: why is the first integration on the right hand side of the second line from below does not contain $dx$?

Comment: The infinitesimal Euclidean arc length is just $\sqrt{dx^2 + dy^2}$, which you can "factor" the $dx$ outside and have an integral depending only on one parameter.

Comment: this is the definition of the infinitesimal Euclidean arc length?

Comment: Yes, see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor

Answer (score 2):

Here one derivation starting from the definitions. Let $\tau:[a,b]\rightarrow R^2:t\rightarrow(t,f(t))$ a parametrization of $C$.

By definition the integral of a differential form $\rho$ is:

$\int_C \rho =\int_{[a,b]} \rho(\tau(t))[\tau'(t)]dt$

, where $\rho(a)[b]$ is the differential form at $a$ acting on vector $b$.

when $\rho=Fdx$, since $\tau'(t)=(1,f'(t))$, $dx[\tau'(t)]=1$ we have:

$\int_C F(x,y) dx =\int_{[a,b]} F(t,f(t))dt$

when $\rho=Fdy$, since $\tau'(t)=(1,f'(t))$, $dy[\tau'(t)]=f'(t)$ we have:

$\int_C F(x,y) dy =\int_{[a,b]} F(t,f(t))f'(t)dt$