# Vanishing of the integration along vertical line

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus

2- Show that if $C$ is a vertical line segment $c \leq y \leq d,$ and if $F$ is a function of 2 variables defined on $C$, then $$\int_{C} F(x,y)dx = 0$$.

I understand that the integration is calculating the area under the curve and because we are integrating on a vertical line so the area is zero. is this the meaning of the question ?

Also I am stucked in the proof as all the theorems and definitions in this section include parametrizations, or shall I use this question [Proving a Line-integration along a parametrized curve identitiy.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3191845/proving-a-line-integration-identitiy)  in proving it?if so how?.  Any help in the proof will be appreciated.

Comment: You should write $\int_C F(x, y)\, dxdy$; otherwise, the integral need not vanish.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro why the integral would not vanish if $dy$ is not written?

Comment: Because I read "the area is zero", so I assumed we were talking about a double integral. Actually, the integral of the differential form $F(x, y)\, dx$ *also* vanishes; this I had overlooked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the area under this curve will be zero. You can do this a bit more rigorously by consider the following limiting process. Consider a line defined by
$$y(x) = c + \frac{x}{\epsilon}(d-c), \quad x\in [0,\epsilon]$$
so that $y(0) = c$ and $y(\epsilon) = d$ and consider
$$|\int_0^{\epsilon} F(x,y(x))dx| \leq \max_{(x,y)\in [0,\epsilon]\times[c,d]} |F(x,y)|\int_0^{\epsilon} dx \leq C\epsilon \rightarrow 0$$
This is just taking the line connecting $(0,c)$ and $(\epsilon,d)$, so in the limit that $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$, this approaches the appropriate segment at $x=0$. This holds for any $x$ so the integral must be zero just as the area under the curve is zero.

Comment: Also can you look at this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3191845/proving-a-line-integration-along-a-parametrized-curve-identitiy  if you have time please?

Comment: Can it be done by the question mentioned by the OP?

Comment: That is precisely what I used as $$\int_C F(x,y)dx = \int_a^bF(x,y(x))dx$$

Comment: It stated "a vertical line segment", so you must describe where that segment is. I chose $x=0$, but any value will give the same result. ie $$C = \{0\}\times [c,d]$$

Comment: what do you mean by approaching the appropriate segment at $x = 0$?

Comment: so you choose the vertical line $x=0$ to represent the vertical line given in the question?

Comment: $C$ must be given by $$C = \{x_0\} \times [c,d]$$ for some $x_0\in \mathbb{R}$. So to justify any line segment you can redefine $y$ to have the domain $[x_0,x_0+\epsilon]$. For simplicity I chose $x_0 = 0$, but any value will work.