# Showing that 2 paths are not equivalent.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

**The definition of equivalent paths is as follows :**

Two paths $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R^n} $ and  $g: [c,d] \rightarrow \mathbb{R^n} $ are equivalent if there exist a $C^{1}$ bijection $\phi: [a,b]\rightarrow [c,d]$ such that $\phi'(t) > 0 $ for all $t \in [a,b]$ and $f = g \circ \phi.$

And I was asked to show that those 2 paths:

$f(t): [0, 2\pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$ and $h(t): [0, 4\pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$. Where $f(t) = \Big( \cos(t), \sin(t)  \Big)$ and $h(t) =\Big( \cos(t), \sin(t)  \Big) $

Are not equivalent.

**My attempt :**

Assume towards contradiction that they are equivalent, then there is a $C^{1}$ bijection $\phi : [0, 2 \pi] \rightarrow [0, 4 \pi] $, such that, $\phi'(t) > 0, \forall t \in [0, 2\pi]$ and $ f = h \circ \phi.$

Which means that $(0,1) = f(0) = (h \circ \phi)(0) = h(\phi(0))= (\cos(\phi (0)), \sin (\phi (0)))$,

which means that $\phi(0) = \phi (2 \pi) = 0 $, contradicting that $\phi $ is an increasing function. hence our first assumption was wrong.

Is my argument correct?

Comment: Why is $\phi(0) = 0$ a contradiction?

Comment: @Dayton21  we will have that $\phi (0) = \phi (2 \pi)$ =0, contracting that $\phi$ is an increasing function.

Comment: Yes exactly, but the statement "$\phi(0) = 0$ or $2\pi$" does not contradict anything. However $\phi(0) = \phi(2\pi)$ does

Comment: I am sorry .... I will correct it ..... but my argument is correct? @Dayton21

Comment: I think it would be sufficient to say you must have $\phi(0) = 0$ and $\phi(2\pi) = 4\pi$ but $f(x) = (1,0)$ exactly twice, however there must be some $x \in (0,4\pi)$ such that $\phi(x) = 2\pi$ which implies $f(x) = (1,0)$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: I don't think you can immediately claim $\phi(0) = \phi(2\pi)$

Comment: I said this because of the properties of the cosine function @Dayton21

Comment: yeah but the options are $\phi(0) \in \{0,2\pi, 4\pi\}$ and $\phi(2\pi) \in \{0, 2\pi,4\pi \}$ so why is it necessary that $\phi(0) = \phi(2\pi)$?

Comment: @Dayton21  could you please look at this if you have time https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3192108/vanishing-of-the-integration-along-vertical-line ?

Comment: it seems like I nearly got your idea @Dayton21  you are saying that cosine function is 1 at all this points .... why I choose the zero only .... correct?

Comment: Exactly, in fact since  $\phi :[0,2\pi]\mapsto [0,4\pi]$, you MUST HAVE $\phi(0) = 0$ and $\phi(2\pi) = 4\pi$ to fit the end points of $f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that there there is a $C^1$ bijection $ϕ:[0,2π]→[0,4π]$, such that, $ϕ′(t)>0,∀t∈[0,2π]$ and $f=h∘ϕ.$

Then we have

$ \cos(t)= \cos( \phi(t))$ and $ \sin(t)= \sin( \phi(t))$ for all $t∈[0,2π]$. We take derivatives and get

$\cos(t)= \cos(\phi(t)) \phi'(t)$ , thus $ \cos(t)=\cos(t) \phi'(t)$ for all $t∈[0,2π]$.

We conclude that $\phi'(t)=1$ for all $t∈[0,2π]$. Hence $\phi(t)=t+c$. Since $\phi(0)=0$. we have $c=0.$

But then we derive $ 4 \pi= \phi( 2 \pi)=2 \pi$, a contradiction.

Comment: So is my argument above correct or no?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3192108/vanishing-of-the-integration-along-vertical-line  Could you look at this if you have time please?

Comment: How do you arrive at the identity in you last line?

Comment: it sems like you divided by 0 -because $\pi/2$ is included in our interval- in your first conclusion in the second line from below...... or what did you do?

Answer (score 1):

(Somewhat) 
alternative hint: If $f,h$ are equivalent, then for each $v\in \Bbb R^n$, the sets $f^{-1}(v)$ and $h^{-1}(v)$ have equal cardinality. $f$ assumes all values once or twice, $h$ does it twice or three times.

Comment: yes I know this argument but I wanted to solve it through the definition given.

Comment: Could you please look at this question if you have https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3192108/vanishing-of-the-integration-along-vertical-line ?

Comment: why is  $f$ and $g$ invertible ?

Comment: or you mean the inverse image?